# Proof that $-\log \Big(\sum_y(\sum_{x}P(x)Q(y\mid x)^{\frac{1}{1+r}})^{r+1}\Big)$ is increasing

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

I want to prove that the following is increasing:

$-\log \Big(\sum_y \sum_{x_1}P_1(x_1)Q_1(y\mid x_1)^{\frac{1}{1+r}}(\sum_{x_2}P_2(x_2)Q_2(y\mid x_2)^{\frac{1}{1+r}})^r\Big)$

Here $P_1, P_2$ are probability mass functions, $Q_1,Q_2$ are transition matrices.

I know for a fact that  I had something like the following

$-\log \Big((\sum_{x} P(x)Q(y\mid x)^{\frac{1}{1+r}})^{r+1}\Big)$

then it would have been increasing. The proof follows Holder's inequality.
since for $r\leq s$
$ (\sum_j q_j b_j^{\frac{1}{r+1}})^{r+1} \geq  (\sum_j q_j b_j^{\frac{1}{s+1}})^{s+1}$

Note1:I don't think taking the derivative is going to help, the expression is extremely ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is not true. Consider $a_i=a, b_i=b, \forall i$ for some $a, b>0$. When $a<b$ the function strictly increases. Second, in the case the inequality is true, it is not necessary that $a_i,b_i\le 1$.

The answer to the modified question is again in the negative. Try the simplest case, where $x$'s are of only $1$ element and $y$ of only $2$ elements, $Q_1(Y|X_1)=[0.6\quad 0.4],\, Q_2(Y|X_2)=[0.1\quad 0.9]$. The function first increases then decreases with respect to positive $r$.

A good question to ask is whether the function of $r$ inside the logarithm is convex. It is not. Neither is it in $[0,1]$, e.g., when $Q_1(Y|X_1)=[0.3075,0.3388,0.3538]^T,\, Q_2(Y|X_2)=[0.4781,0.0001,0.5218]^T$. It is also not convex as a function of $u:=\frac{1}{1+r}$ either. $f\big(\frac{1}{u}-1\big),\, u\in[0,1]$ as defined below can have an inflection point. $f(r=\infty)=\sum_i\prod_kb_{ik}^{q_k}\le \sum_i\sum_kq_kb_{ik}=1$ by Jensen's inequality on the logarithm.

For my own benefit and possibly others, I would like to show the simple fact that
$$f(r):= \sum_i\Big(\sum_j p_ja_{ij}^\frac{1}{1+r}\Big)\Big(\sum_k q_kb_{ik}^\frac{1}{1+r}\Big)^r\le 1$$
where all variables are nonnegative and $\sum_i a_{ij}=\sum_i b_{ij}=1$ and $\sum_j p_j=\sum_k q_k=1$.

To this end, we have
$$\sum_jp_ja_{ij}^\frac{1}{1+r}\le \Big(\sum_jp_ja_{ij}\Big)^\frac{1}{1+r}=:x_i^\frac{1}{1+r},\quad \sum_k q_kb_{ik}^\frac{1}{1+r}\le \Big(\sum_jq_kb_{ik}\Big)^\frac{1}{1+r}=:y_i^\frac{1}{1+r}$$
by Jensen's inequality.
\begin{align}
f(r)&\le \sum_i x_i^\frac{1}{1+r}y_i^\frac{r}{1+r} \\
&\le \Big(\sum_i x_i\Big)^\frac{1}{1+r}\Big(\sum_i y_i\Big)^\frac{r}{1+r} \\
&=1
\end{align}
by Holder's inequality and
$$\sum_i x_i =\sum_jp_j\sum_ia_{ij}=1=\sum_jq_j\sum_ib_{ij}=\sum_iy_i.$$ The desired upper bound is established.

Comment: Oh you are right. I did not think of that, so I omitted some parts of the problem to make it simpler. My problem is actually the following:

Comment: I changed the question, do you think it is correct now?

Comment: I have added a counterexample to your modified question. You should be able to discover this by trying random matrices of $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It appears you agree with my answer. Would you accept my answer and upvote it?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: I didn't however understand your convexity argument. How do you argue that it is not convex in $r$? What about the range $0<r \leq 1$?

Comment: You can construct a counterexample by trying some random matrices. I have added in my answer a counterexample for the convexity in $[0,1]$. Why are you particularly interested in that range?

Comment: And by the way, I plotted your example, it looks convex to me... ? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thank you! $r$ for me is the parameter I used in bounding a union bound i.e. $P(\cup_i A_i)\leq [\sum_i P(A_i)]^r$, for this, $r$ has to be in $[0,1]$. Just one more thing, do you have any idea that for the following what should $s$ (probably as a function of $r$) be to minimize the expression $\sum_i \sum_j p_j a_{ij}^{1-sr}(\sum_k q_k b_{ik}^s)^r$?

Comment: You should plot the graph with my parameters on $[0, 2]$ and look really carefully at it probably with a straight ruler. Let me know if you still do not see it being concave at $r=1$. I have not looked at the problem with $s$ yet. Maybe you can pose it as another question here. Please provide the link here if you do.

Comment: Ok, now I am confused. Assume $u=\frac{1}{1+r}$. Then $\frac{r}{1+r}=1-u$. Also assume the simplified case that $p_j$ and $q_k$ are 1 for a single value of $i$ and $j$. Then the function $\log(\sum_i a_i^{\frac{1}{1+r}}b_i^{\frac{r}{1+r}})$ with $u=\frac{1}{1+r}$ corresponds to $\log(\sum_i a_i^u b_i^{1-u})$ which is convex function of $u$. Hence $f''(u)>0$. Second derivative of $u$ with respect to $r$ is also positive so $f$ should be a convex function of $r$ as well. This contradicts your counterexample. How is that?

Comment: $g(u):=\sum_ia_i^ub_i^{1-u}$ is convex but its logarithm may not be. Also $g(u(r))$ may not be convex with respect to $r$. Review the chain rule.

Comment: $f(u)=\log \sum_i a_i^u b_i^{1-u}=\log \sum_i a_i^{\theta x+\bar{\theta}y}b_i^{\theta(1-x)+\bar{\theta}(1-y)}\leq \log[ \Big( \sum_i a_i^x b_i^{1-x} \Big)^\theta \Big(\sum_i a_i^y b_i^{1-y}\Big)^\bar{\theta}]=\theta f(x)+\bar{\theta}f(y)$ So the logarithm is also convex. Right? Chain rule was correct I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You are right about the convexity of your $f$. Your reasoning about $g(u(r))$ is still wrong due to the sign of $g'(u)$ in the chain rule.

Comment: Just want to emphasize that when the number of states of $x_1$ and $x_2$  is greater than $1$, the $f$ defined in my answer is no longer convex, as pointed out in my answer. I doubt $\ln f$ will be either.